# Fade background image in and out with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

So far, I've tried a bunch of things to the effect of the following, without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0;

while (true) {
    /* change background-image of #slide using some variation
    of animate or fadeIn/fadeOut with or without setTimeout */
    x++;
}
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this can be done, because `background-image` doesn't support any kind of fading. You'll have to use normal images for this

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can fade background colors but not background images. The way to work around this is to have your images as `<img>` tags and hide them by default `display:none;`. Give your images `position:absolute` and `z-index:-1` so they act like backgrounds and are behind everything else.

Here's a quick example of images fading one after the other.

**HTML**

```
<img src=".." />
<img src=".." />
```

**CSS**

```
img{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:-1;
 display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function test() {
    $("img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).delay(3000* index).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut();
    });
}
test();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any idea how I can make this loop infinitely?

Comment: How to do with 1 img tag and not two?

Answer (score 2):

You can fade backgound-images!
in and out!

jQuery:

```
$('#yourdiv').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css("background-image", "url(image.jpeg)").animate({opacity: 1}, 2500);
```

Edit:

This will fade the whole div not onley the background-image.

Comment: This fades the whole div, not only the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't directly fade-in a `background-image`. You can fade-in a solitary element containing only a `background-image`...

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/fv5dc/)

Answer (score 0):

I got here because I was looking for a solution to fading background images based on a `<select>` option change.  I combined what I had already written with Hussein's jsfiddle above and came up with this [jsfiddle.net/v4BMC/](http://jsfiddle.net/v4BMC/).

This initially stacks two identical images on top of each other. When the `<select>` is changed, the top image's style attribute is removed, the bottom image's src is changed and the top image is faded out to reveal the bottom one. (The top image finishes with a `style="display:none"` which needs to be removed at the beginning of the operation, otherwise it doesn't work.)

Hope this is useful to someone else and not too irrelevant to be included here!

Comment: And you may need to [preload the images first.](http://chipsandtv.com/articles/jquery-image-preload)

Answer (score 0):

Here a [demo](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/pen/dyJZxZr) to fade `background-image` by using the `opacity` and `transition` CSS properties with javascript/jQuery:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#textarea" ).focusin(function(){
    $( "#blur" ).css({
      "opacity" : "1.0",
      "transition" : "opacity 600ms ease-in-out"
    });
  }).focusout(function(){
    $( "#blur" ).css({
      "opacity" : "0",
      "transition" : "opacity 600ms ease-in-out"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://vpsland.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/linux-vps-benefits-g.jpg");
}

#textarea {
  width: 50%;
}

#blur {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://static1.makeuseofimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/linux-overdrive.jpg?q=50&fit=contain&w=1500&h=750&dpr=1.5");
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<input id="textarea" type="text" placeholder="Focus here to trigger the transition...">
<div id="blur"></div>
```