# Replace backgroundColor with backgroundImage in jQuery animate effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a working fade in/fade out jQuery example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mcgarriers/NJe63/6/

However, I'm wondering if it is possible to replace the **background-color red effect** with a **background image**?

Many thanks for any pointers

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/fading-in-a-background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying something like this?

I altered the code from your jsfiddle link.

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css('background', 'url(http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Hello_Kitty_Pink_2981.jpg)').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 0).css('background', 'white');
});​
```

Comment: I have tried this here: http://jsfiddle.net/mcgarriers/NJe63/12/ but as you can see it doesn't work as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: you should remove `background:white` from css

Comment: Hi Dariush. Sadly this still doesn't seem to help. My Google logo image completely disappears when it should remain always. And no bg image loads :/

Comment: I tried it again and it works. I updated the code a little as well.
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css('background', 'url(http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Hello_Kitty_Pink_2981.jpg)').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css('background', 'white');
});;​

Comment: thanks for the reply - can you update the code in your first 'answer' as stackoverflow seems to have cropped your answer in the comments.

Comment: Sorry. I need to keep Google logo displayed always. I just want to change white background to 'hello kitty' image on hover. Is this possible?

Comment: Code is updated to keep the google logos, the opacity just had to be set back to 1 on moueout.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.
Can you tell me why the Google Logo appears to 'blink' on mouseover?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS3. You could create a div tag to the size of your choice around the image then use a basic CSS3 transition.

```
  #yourdiv a {
     background-color: #FFF;
}

#yourdiv a:hover {
     background-color: #000;
     -webkit-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
     -moz-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
     -o-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
     transition: background-color 600ms linear;
}
```

Or you can have a image fade into another with CSS3:
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg1/

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer in my question - sadly this needs to work in IE so I don't think I can use this answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fadein/fadeout background-image of a HTML element, but you can with background-color.

Would it possibly be your solution? [Fade background image in and out with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533171/fade-background-image-in-and-out-with-jquery)