# jquery fade background image and p tags

Tags: jquery, fade

I want to be able to fade just the background image and the p tags within the banner div. Everything else shouldn't fade. It would also be good for the first background and p tag to show from the off.
Thank you

```
var imgs = ['http://www.google.com/logos/1998/googleburn.jpg', 'http://www.google.com/logos/1998/googlebeta.jpg', 'http://www.google.com/logos/1999/googlepump.gif'],
    i = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    $('.banner').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgs[i] + ')').find('p:eq(' + i + ')').show().siblings().hide()
            .end().end().fadeIn(300, function () {
            i++;
            if (i === imgs.length) {
                i = 0
            };
        });
    });
}, 5000)
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samjsharples/pNTqP/8/)

Comment: everything else ?? there is nothing else other than those two ??

Comment: You can't fade background image like this...

Comment: you can fade color but not background image. check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533171/fade-background-image-in-and-out-with-jquery

Comment: You could add the background and p tags on a separate div and fade it away animating the opacity value.

Answer (score 0):

i modify a bit your code

http://jsfiddle.net/pNTqP/9/

html

```
<img class="banner" />
```

javascript

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('.banner').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).attr('src',  imgs[i]).find('p:eq(' + i + ')').show().siblings().hide()
            .end().end().fadeIn(300, function () {
            i++;
            if (i === imgs.length) {
                i = 0
            };
        });
    });
}, 5000)
```